# What is the difference between ResponseEntity<?> and ResponseEntity<Object> and ResponseEntity<MyCustomClass>

Tags: java, spring, controller

Right now I need my controller to return 2 different type of Object based on business logic , So my question is should i use

```
ResponseEntity <?>
```

or should I use:

```
ResponseEntity <Object>
```

What are the difference between this ***return types*** and why should I use them?

Does it make any cahnges to JSON returned by Spring controller?

I'm asking about ***return types not input parameter.***

I use Spring MVC 4.

Comment: my question is a bit different. I'm asking in regards of controller